# SQL join query - selecting from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join, nested

I have a query which checks a table for a number of fields.  The two tables I am interested in are: PERSON & PERSON_ALTERNATE_ID.

I want to modify my query to also return the value stored in person_alternate_id (if the particular person indeed has one)

```
select distinct person.person_id, person_name, person_address
from person join person_alternate_id
on
person.person_id=person_alternate_id.person_id
where person.person_id
in (10001,10002,10003);
```

Can anyone suggest how I could do that?  I was looking at nested select examples, but I wasn't able to implement a suitable change to my query that achieved what I require.  At the moment, the query only returns fields I need from the PERSON table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the person may or may not have an alternate id, you should use a left join:

```
select person.person_id, person_name, person_address, person_alternate_id.*
from person 
left join person_alternate_id
on person.person_id=person_alternate_id.person_id
where person.person_id
in (10001,10002,10003);
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to do the trick.  However, it seems to ignore the distinct, and pull multiple records now, I only need one example of 10001.  Now, I get numerous instances...  Can you advise?

Comment: I don't understand why and what you have duplicated: Persons or Person_alternate_ids. If distinct does not help you, let me know: 10001 appear multiple times in table Person or in Person_alternate_id?

Comment: I figured it out, thanks.  PERSON_ALT_ID on the second table, can have multiple values based on another ID_TYPE field.  This is why distinct wasn't enough... I modified the query to explicitly search ID's of a certain TYPE.  Thanks for your help. :)